# Resolution failed exception in Xamarin IOS prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

I have an iOS application written in Xamarin and I am getting a Unity Exceptions Resolution Failed exception when I try and run the application in iOS. However this error does not happen when I run the android version of the application. The exception is being thrown while the initalize function from prism is taking place.

Here is a snippet from my app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        this.RegisterLocal(containerRegistry);
        this.RegisterServices(containerRegistry);  
        this.RegisterPagesForNavigation(containerRegistry);
    }
```

This code all executes and passes.

This is the iOS initialization

```
Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        PullToRefreshLayoutRenderer.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App(new IosInitializer()));

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public class IosInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.Register<IUAirshipUpdate, UAirshipUpdate>();
        }
    }
```

This code also executes

The exception being thrown is an argument null exception indicating that IModuleCatelog is not present. I do not understand why it is looking for that module and can not find it. The source code on GitHub indicates that class was registered.

Comment: What's the idea behind the implementation of `RegisterTypes` on your `App.xaml.cs`? That should be the place where you register your pages and other services you might implement, I don't think you should be registering the container itself like that. Check this section on Prism's Getting Started guide: https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html#navigating-to-your-new-page

Comment: Register types calls those functions that are listed. I never register the container

Comment: My bad, I read and replied in a hurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused because linker behavior for IOS application was set to full and that causes issues with Unity IOC Container.